# Is $\text{Sup}f(x)$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

This is my assumption: Is this function $F(h)$ continuous?
$$F(h):=\sup_{x\in [a, h]} f(x)$$

where $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a, b]$ and $h\in[a,b]$.

I think this function is continuous. But I don't know how to prove.

Comment: +1, good question. I don't know the answer, but I hasten to add that this is an example of ["serialization"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273266/whats-serialization-really-called-and-is-there-any-theory-surrounding-it).

Comment: A typo in your question. Replace $a+h$ by $h$ in your first equation.